# Monitor project progress in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, progress

I am running a project in eclipse and I want to monitor the progress. I did window---Show View -- Progress. However, the progress section remains empty and I dont know if the project is running or not.

I know this is a very naive question and I searched a lot on google but I didnt understand anything from these links:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_progress_monitors%3F
https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_switch_from_using_a_Progress_dialog_to_the_Progress_view%3F

And, many more that I read. I am not a pro in JAVA, so can anyone please tell me in layman terms, how can I monitor my project. Thanks a ton..!!!

Comment: I think your project has to report the progress to the monitor, i.e. you have to incorporate the progress monitoring code into your project.

Comment: Can you please define "Monitor"? Is it that you want to monitor your variables as the program runs? If that's the case, make breakpoints (double click the small space beside the line number in a line of code, a circle should appear) and go into debug mode. There's a bug icon on the upper part of eclipse. That's what I use to monitor my values.

Comment: Progress monitors and the progress view are used by Eclipse plugins - are you writing a plugin? If this is just a normal Java program you are running they can't be used.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. @theguywhodreams: I did that already. @ DigitalNinja: I am trying to understand how to write these codes. So, like I write them before "main" or after. Like, is there an example I can read. Many thanks once again..!!!!